# Linker errors when trying to enable FFmpeg stagefright support

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to use stagefright for HW accelerated decoding in my Android movie player
based on FFmpeg - version 0.10.2 "Freedom". I have successfully built all the
libraries using the build script in tools directory. However, I have many linker
errors related to stagefright e.g.:

```
undefined reference to android::OMXClient::disconnect()
undefined reference to android::MediaBuffer::MediaBuffer(unsigned int)
```

I thought the binaries built with stagefright support are self-contained and do
not need any other stuff to link with. Am I doing something wrong? Should I add
libstagefright.so to my project? I think it would cause many troubles with
compatibility...

Is it compatible with API 8 or only API 9 and above?

Many thanks,
Vita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created VPlayer for Android. And used stagefright in VPlayer. But I don't recommend you use the libstagefright.cpp in ffmpeg, as it's too buggy and not portable.

However, if you wanna build it, you should follow the build instruction in ffmpeg, or you may try this configure [FFMpeg Android Stagefright SIGSEGV error (h264 decode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098167/ffmpeg-android-stagefright-sigsegv-error-h264-decode)

Be sure to replace some paths to your environment.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! You already responded to one of my question regarding movie player based on FFmpeg :) I have VPlayer installed on my device and use it as a reference together with MX Player. 
I finally linked my app - after some consultation with the author of that support in FFmpeg, but it does not work.
May I ask you a question regarding HW acceleration directly via email? I am not developing competitor for your VPlayer or other player on the market, it is closed solution for a special purpose and I really need some consultation, I can send you a few hundred bucks if you help me.

Comment: Hi, I have sent you two emails, have you received them?