# Android how to increase ffmpeg mp4 perfromance?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg, decoding

I have detected that function `avcodec_decode_audio3` works slow with mp4 format, here my code cycle for decoding audio:

```
while (av_read_frame(av_format_context, &packet) >= 0 && is_play == 1) {
        if (av_codec_context->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
                && is_play == 1) {
            int out_size = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE;
            int size = packet.size;
            int n;
            int dataLength = size;
            int decoded = 0;
            while (size > 0) {

                //start measure time
                gettimeofday(&tvBegin, NULL);

                int len = avcodec_decode_audio3(av_codec_context,
                        (int16_t *) pAudioBuffer, &out_size, &packet);

                //stop measure time
                gettimeofday(&tvEnd, NULL);
                timeval_subtract(&tvDiff, &tvEnd, &tvBegin);

                LOGI("%d", tvDiff.tv_usec / 1000);
                LOGI("len='%d'", len);
                LOGI("out_size='%d'", out_size);

                if (len < 0) {
                    break;
                    return 1;
                }
                if (out_size > 0) {



                    jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array,
                            NULL);
                    memcpy(bytes, (int16_t *) pAudioBuffer, out_size);
                    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bytes, 0);
                    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, play, array, out_size,
                            is_play);

                }
                size -= len;
            }

        }
        if (packet.data)
            av_free_packet(&packet);

    }
```

But with other formats like flac and mp3 it works fine. `avcodec_decode_audio3` take about 1-2 milisecounds for decoding mp3 frame with `out_size` = 4608 but with the same frame size in mp4 decoding take about 6-7 millisecounds. I got my build script from [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/servestream/code/ffmpeg/scripts/arm-build.sh).

Does it normal behavior? Is any way to increase performance of decoding mp4?

Comment: It's a more complex codec, so I would not be shocked to learn that it takes more processing time to decode.

Comment: hi.. ffmpeg android can get compiled using cygwin in android ? i have tried it but not able to compile and generate .so files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u could search on hardware acceleration...

"H/W Accelerated H.264 Decoding on Android"

for example:

[How to use hardware accelerated video decoding on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321825/how-to-use-hardware-accelerated-video-decoding-on-android)

http://readlist.com/lists/mplayerhq.hu/mplayer-users/5/26751.html

IMO - ffmpeg is still mostly in software but on the newer versions of android, you may be able to find some stagefright API's providing GPU accelerated way to access the framebuffer??