# How to use android/google software decoder at app level

Tags: android, decoding

I have a video that currently in Android uses the hardware accelerated decoder. Is there any way that I can customize it to use the android software decoder at the app layer? If so, how do I go about it? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Thanks for the help - isn't that more for animation and drawing? I was looking for something closer to video playback.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for software video decoding. Also, see [this article](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android) relating to ffmpeg and Android.

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321825/how-to-use-hardware-accelerated-video-decoding-on-android) contains further information regarding this topic of encoding for Android.