# Which has the most low latency between NDK or Java MediaCodec api?

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, decode, android-mediacodec

I'm building a live-streaming app that streams the content to a client. 
I'm wondering what would be the fastest way to decode a stream ?
Coding the client using NDK or using Java media codec api ?

I've seen Kodi/FFMPEG using the NDK and ExoPlayer using the Java.

Thanks for any pointers :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427289/developing-h264-hardware-decoder-android-stagefright-or-openmax-il

Comment: Interesting! But MediaCodec API is available since API 21 on NDK so you don't need to go through that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both NDK and Java MediaCodec APIs use the same native backend library. Decoding performance is the same for both cases (of course Java API introduces extra overhead because of JNI mechanism, but it is much less than actual decoding time). So just choose whatever you want. But note than NDK API is available only at Android 5.0+ devices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
I think I will go with Java as it's the language I'm the most proficient in :)