# H264 Hardware Decoder OpenMax IL for QualComm's Snapdragon

Tags: android, c++, h.264, hardware-acceleration, qualcomm

I am trying to develop an Android H264 hardware accelerated video decoder for Qualcomm's Snapdragon using stagefright. But I couldn't find any straight-forward resource to achieve it. Can anyone help me with some useful link or resouce?

Comment: What do you mean by straight-forward. I've found: https://source.android.com/devices/media.html#codecs which would have lead to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/ which gives part number directories for headers, but its a direction for investigation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use hardware accelerated video decoding on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321825/how-to-use-hardware-accelerated-video-decoding-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should use media codec API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html. This API will internally use HW accelerated codecs if they are available on the device.